# Getting GC overhead limit exceeded because of spring MVC + hibernate at bean loading

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, garbage-collection

I am new to `spring mvc` framework. Here I am getting GC overhead limit exceeded exception when I deploy `war` file of my application by starting `Apache Tomcat 7` service.

**bean.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">

    <bean id="loadproperties" class="com.dyulok.dewa.utility.ProjectProperties">
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>file:${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/dyulokeventwebapplication_project.properties
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>${jdbc.mysql.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>${jdbc.mysql.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${jdbc.mysql.password}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="validationQuery">
            <value>SELECT 1</value>
        </property>
        <property name="testOnBorrow">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class"></prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value> com.dyulok.dewa.model.event.Event</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.event.ConferenceEvent</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.organizer.EventOrganizer</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.inbox.Inbox</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.inbox.Message</value>

                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.schedule.SubEvent</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.schedule.ConferenceSession</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.speakers.Speaker</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.venue.Venue</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.venue.SubVenue</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.exhibitors.Exhibitor</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.exhibitors.ExhibitorCollection</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.feedback.FeedBack</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.feedback.EventFeedback</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.feedback.SubEventFeedback</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.schedule.SubEventResource</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.image.Image</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.register.RegistrationMetadata</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.register.RegistrationData</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.speakers.CallForSpeaker</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.displayoptions.ConferenceTabDisplayOptions
                </value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.user.User</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.user.UserFriends</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.organizer.EventOrganizerAccountDetails
                </value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.ticket.TicketDetails</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.ticket.TicketDiscount</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.ticket.TransactionalDetail</value>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa.model.payouts.PayoutsTransaction</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>

        <property name="annotatedPackages">
            <list>
                <value>com.dyulok.dewa</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="dataSource" />
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="EventDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.event.EventDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="EventDataServiceImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.event.EventDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="eventdatadao">
            <ref local="EventDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="subEventDataService">
            <ref local="SubEventDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="inboxDataService">
            <ref local="InboxDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="exhibitorDataService">
            <ref local="ExhibitorDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="feedbackDataService">
            <ref local="FeedbackDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="speakerDataService">
            <ref local="SpeakerDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="imageDataService">
            <ref local="ImageDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="organizerDataService">
            <ref local="EventOrganizerDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="callForSpeakerDataService">
            <ref local="CallForSpeakerDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="registrationMetadataDataService">
            <ref local="RegistrationMetadataDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="registrationDataService">
            <ref local="RegistrationDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="conferenceTabDisplayOptionsDataService">
            <ref local="ConferenceTabDisplayOptionsDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="ticketDetailsDataService">
            <ref local="TicketDetailsDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ExhibitorDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.exhibitor.ExhibitorDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="ExhibitorDataServiceImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.exhibitor.ExhibitorDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="exhibitordatadao">
            <ref local="ExhibitorDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="FeedbackDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.feedback.FeedbackDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="FeedbackDataServiceImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.feedback.FeedbackDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="feedbackdatadao">
            <ref local="FeedbackDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="InboxDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.inbox.InboxDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="InboxDataServiceImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.inbox.InboxDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="inboxdatadao">
            <ref local="InboxDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="EventOrganizerDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.organizer.EventOrganizerDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="EventOrganizerDataServiceImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.organizer.EventOrganizerDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="organizerdatadao">
            <ref local="EventOrganizerDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="eventdataservice">
            <ref local="EventDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
         <property name="organizeraccountdataservice">
            <ref local="EventOrganizerAccountDataServiceImpl"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="EventOrganizerAccountDataDaoImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.organizer.EventOrganizerAccountDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="EventOrganizerAccountDataServiceImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.organizer.EventOrganizerAccountDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="organizeraccountdatadao">
            <ref local="EventOrganizerAccountDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>

    </bean>


    <bean id="SubEventDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.schedule.SubEventDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcTemplate">
            <ref local="jdbcTemplate" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="SubEventDataServiceImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.schedule.SubEventDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="subeventdatadao">
            <ref local="SubEventDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="SpeakerDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.speaker.SpeakerDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcTemplate">
            <ref local="jdbcTemplate" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="SpeakerDataServiceImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.speaker.SpeakerDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="speakerdatadao">
            <ref local="SpeakerDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="subEventDataService">
            <ref local="SubEventDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="imageDataService">
            <ref local="ImageDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ImageDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.image.ImageDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="ImageDataServiceImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.image.ImageDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="imagedatadao">
            <ref local="ImageDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="RegistrationMetadataDataDaoImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.register.RegistrationMetadataDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="RegistrationMetadataDataServiceImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.register.RegistrationMetadataDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="registrationMetadataDataDao">
            <ref local="RegistrationMetadataDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="RegistrationDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.register.RegistrationDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="RegistrationDataServiceImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.register.RegistrationDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="registrationdatadao">
            <ref local="RegistrationDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="TicketDetailsDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.ticket.TicketDetailsDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="TicketDetailsDataServiceImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.ticket.TicketDetailsDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="ticketdetailsdatadao">
            <ref local="TicketDetailsDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="ticketdiscountdataservice">
            <ref local="TicketDiscountDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="TicketDiscountDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.ticket.TicketDiscountDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="TicketDiscountDataServiceImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.ticket.TicketDiscountDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="ticketdiscountdatadao">
            <ref local="TicketDiscountDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="TransactionDetailsDataDaoImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.ticket.TransactionDetailsDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="TransactionalDetailDataServiceImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.ticket.TransactionalDetailDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="transactionaldetaildatadao">
            <ref local="TransactionDetailsDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="registrationDataService">
            <ref local="RegistrationDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="eventOrganizerDataService">
            <ref local="EventOrganizerDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="userDataService">
            <ref local="UserDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="PayoutsTransactionDataDaoImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.payouts.PayoutsTransactionDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="PayoutsTransactionDataServiceImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.payouts.PayoutsTransactionDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="payoutsTransactionDataDao">
            <ref local="PayoutsTransactionDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="CallForSpeakerDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.speaker.CallForSpeakerDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="CallForSpeakerDataServiceImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.speaker.CallForSpeakerDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="callForSpeakerDataDao">
            <ref local="CallForSpeakerDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ConferenceTabDisplayOptionsDataDaoImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.displayoptions.ConferenceTabDisplayOptionsDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="ConferenceTabDisplayOptionsDataServiceImpl"
        class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.displayoptions.ConferenceTabDisplayOptionsDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="displayoptionsdatadao">
            <ref local="ConferenceTabDisplayOptionsDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="VenueDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.venue.VenueDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="VenueDataServiceImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.venue.VenueDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="venuedatadao">
            <ref local="VenueDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="eventdataservice">
            <ref local="EventDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="UserDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.user.UserDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcTemplate">
            <ref local="jdbcTemplate" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="UserDataServiceImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.user.UserDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDataDao">
            <ref local="UserDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="registrationDataService">
            <ref local="RegistrationDataServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="accountDataService">
            <ref local="EventOrganizerAccountDataServiceImpl"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="UserFriendsDataDaoImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.dao.user.UserFriendsDataDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="UserFriendsDataServiceImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.user.UserFriendsDataServiceImpl">
        <property name="userFriendsDataDao">
            <ref local="UserFriendsDataDaoImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    
     <bean id="SystemDataServiceImpl" class="com.dyulok.dewa.service.system.SystemDataServiceImpl" >
        <property name="eventDataService">
            <ref local="EventDataServiceImpl"/>
        </property>
         <property name="userDataService">
           <ref local="UserDataServiceImpl"/>
        </property>
        <property name="organizerDataService">
           <ref local="EventOrganizerDataServiceImpl"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="event_data_hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate"
        lazy-init="true">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

but when I simply run the command `catalina run`, command prompt shows following trace. Application runs successfully without any error.

**Catalina log when run by command**

Looks like my file is too big. So I have posted [Catalina log command](http://tny.cz/bf1079c9).

**Catalina log when run by service**

It contains error. [Catalina log service](http://tny.cz/c3c0eca8)

I found lot of people saying increase the `jvm size`. I would have done that, but the question is why does application run by command line and does not run by starting tomcat7 service.

**Update:** Increasing jvm heap size to 2 GB did not solve my problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When starting Tomcat from the command line it will use the JAVA_HOME and the Path variable to locate the JRE to start the JVM.

The service version [AUTO mode](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) will find the JVM from the Windows registry.

Check your window registry to see which JVM does the service version actually uses. Maybe you have more than one JDKs installed on your system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have checked that my system has only one JDK but have two JRE.